# Importing time and date strings from CSV to DateProperty / TimeProperty in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I'm trying to read a file with cells that have the date format "XX/XX/XXXX" from a csv file as well as with cells that contain the time format "XX:XX:XX" using DateProperty and TimeProperty in App Engine (python) respectively. I originally did something similar using DateTimeProperty:

```
x = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
row[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%m/%d/%Y")
x = row[1]
```

but this also returned a blank time of 00:00:00, which I don't want.

I added .date() onto the end of
    datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%m/%d/%Y") 
but got this error:
    "BadValueError: Expected datetime, got datetime.time(23, 59)"
where the 23, 59 comes from one of the time cells "23:59:00".

EDIT: I can get rid of the error above by changing the x = ndb.DateTimeProperty() to just x=ndb.DateProperty(), however when viewing this in the Datastore Viewer on the app engine, it still posts 00:00:00 in addition to the date; I'm just looking for the date.

Comment: can you post couple of lines of that CSV file?

Comment: They're just a mix of integers, dates, times, strings:

3084,5/1/2013,12:45:16,depot
1026,6/7/2012,1:13:15,property

Comment: Can you show us the output of `print row[1]` before assigning it to x?